# Adding NSMutableDictonary to NSMutableArray but objects being replaced

Tags: cocoa, nsmutabledictionary

How come whenever I add a new object NSMutableDictionay to my NSMutableArray it replaces my previous object?

For example:

```
[appDelegate.tracksDict setObject:currentTrackTitle forKey:@"track_title"];
[appDelegate.tracksDict setObject:currentTrackTopic forKey:@"topic"];
[appDelegate.tracksArray addObject:[appDelegate.tracksDict copy]];
```

Its printing...

```
2010-10-01 14:03:35.021 XML[48889:207]Tracks Array: {
    topic = "Cold Calling";
    "track_title" = "Sleeping and selling";
}
2010-10-01 14:03:35.021 XML[48889:207]Tracks Array: {
    topic = "Gate Keeper";
    "track_title" = "Selling like a chicken";
}
2010-10-01 14:03:35.021 XML[48889:207]Tracks Array: {
    topic = "Gate Keeper";
    "track_title" = "Don't you try to sell";
}
```

Instead of something like...

```
2010-10-01 14:03:35.021 XML[48889:207]Tracks Array: {
    topic = "Cold Calling";
    track_title = "Sleeping and selling";

    topic = "Gate Keeper";
    track_title = "Selling like a chicken";

    topic = "Gate Keeper";
    track_title = "Selling like a chicken";
}
```

I'm sure its something stupid since I don't know the language very well.

Comment: Don't forget to release any object you create by `copy`. See the Memory Management Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is hard to follow based on the "print" you posted, but it sounds like you want an NSArray of NSDictionary objects. NSDictionary can only hold a single object for a given key but can have (virtually) unlimited keys. It looks like what you need is to build an array of dictionaries, one per track.

Comment: And the output the OP provided looks more like a dictionary of arrays. An array of dictionaries is a better idea.

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry I had made a mistake. It should be an Array of Dictionaries as you guys said. But whenever I add a new dictionary it is replace the pervious one I had added. Instead of retaining all of the Dictionaries.

Comment: Urgh, nevermind I have misunderstood completely what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks anyway guys. I need to ask better questions next time.

Comment: Better questions not only lead to better answers from others, but they can often lead you to your own answer. :-) Sometimes just taking the time to phrase a question carefully is enough to clarify the problem so the solution is obvious before even asking.